# Google Sheets - Search column value in another column if found copy second column's value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a situation like below:
Column A has some values. Column B has more values. Now I want to check if Column B contains values from Column A. If it contains then print values from Column B to Column C.
Please note that all values are unique so no confusion of finding value more than once.

```
Column A
john.doe
alice.white

Column B
violinhi@yahoo.com.
augusto@yahoo.ca
bwcarty@att.net
dprice@msn.com
alice.white@hotmail.com
staikos@optonline.net
psharpe@mac.com
john.doe@gmail.com
andale@yahoo.com
magusnet@icloud.com

Column C(This is expected output)
john.doe@gmail.com
alice.white@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way ..

```
=filter(B2:B, match(regexextract(B2:B, "(.*)@"), A2:A, 0))
```

[image]

Or maybe

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), vlookup(A2:A, {split(B2:B, "@"), B2:B}, 3, 0),))
```